# Inequalities and multiplication with intervals

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Let $x,y\in (a,b)$ with $a>0$ and $b>a$. Then $xy\in$ $(a^2,b^2)$.

Proof: Without loss of generality suppose $xy> b^2$. Then $x>\frac{b^2}{y}$. As $y\leq b$ and $b>0$, we have $x>b$, which is a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you justify the first inequality? Take $a=0,b=1$ and $x=0.5,y=0.5$, there's no reason for $xy>b$.

Comment: @David look at what I wrote again, please. I didn't mean to include that part.

Comment: Apologies, I did not read your proof properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Alternate proof: since $x,y\in (a,b)$ and $a>0$, $x$ and $y$ are positive. The fact that $x,y\in (a,b)$ is equivalent to the four statements
$$a<x,\ x<b,\ a<y,\ \text{and}\ y<b.$$

If you want to be very explicit, you can write, for example, that there exist positive numbers $c$ and $d$ such that

$$x+c=b\ \text{and}\ y+d=b.$$

Now $(x+c)(y+d)=b^2$, and thus $xy+xd+cy+cd=b^2$. All of these terms are still positive, and thus $xy<b^2$. Now prove similarly that $a^2<xy$.

---

I should add that I prefer your proof because it is much shorter. However, as Kabo mentioned, you should begin by somehow clarifying that you are arguing for contradiction. Otherwise a grader might not read past the first few words. You also should probably be a bit more careful with a few of your claims (since this is an exercise in proof writing). In particular, you definitely need a strict inequality $y<b$.

Comment: thank you very much for the amazing answer. You are completely right.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct but the writing is not at all good. You should say the following:

If possible let $xy \geq b^{2}$. Then $x \geq \frac {b^{2}} y$. Since $y <b$ we get $x >b$ which is a  contradiction.

Be careful to distinguish between strict and loose inequalities.